# How to run a shell command in Bluemix Spark notebook running scala?

Tags: scala, ibm-cloud, jupyter-notebook

Is there a way to run shell commands from a Bluemix Spark notebook running a scala kernel? In a Bluemix Spark python notebook, you can simply prefix the shell command with a "!". There does not appear to be any line or shell magics (ex. %%sh) defined in the scala kernel to provide similar functionality. For example, how can one download a file for analysis with wget from within scala notebook?

Comment: This is also applicable for EMR notebooks with Scala kernel

Answer (score 2):

First import the package "import sys.process._"

import sys.process._

and then run following:-

Simply put your command text in double quotes and follow it by exclamation(!)

"wget https://github.com/charles2588/sparkjobs/raw/master/abc.txt" !

Thanks,

Charles.